# lambdas with duktape (using C++)

Tags: c++, lambda, duktape

I want to call `duk_push_c_function()` with a lambda defined in C++, a bit like this:

```cpp
SomeObjType parameter;
// store stuff in 'parameter'
auto myLambda = [parameter](duk_context* ctx) {
  // do stuff with parameter
  return (duk_ret_t)1;
}

duk_push_c_function(ctx, myLambda , 1);
```

My problem is that this won't compile because `myLambda` is not a C function:

```
error C2664: 'duk_idx_t duk_push_c_function(duk_context *,duk_c_function,duk_idx_t)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'MyObjectName::<lambda_07f401c134676d14b7ddd718ad05fbe6>' to 'duk_c_function'
```

Is there a nice way of passing a nameless function with parameters into duktape?

Comment: A lambda is not a `c_function`.  A non-capturing lambda can decay into a plain function pointer but not a capturing one.

Answer (score 3):

`duk_push_c_function()` expects a plain C-style function pointer.  A **non-capturing** lambda can *decay* into such a pointer, but a **capturing** lambda cannot.  So, you will have to store a pointer to your `parameter` in a stash where your lambda can reach it:

> Stashes allow C code to store internal state which can be safely isolated from ECMAScript code.